# Convert a Bitmap to a N*N*N*N Byte Array for Firebase ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, android-bitmap, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to use the android camera to feed an image as input to my Convolutional Neural Network Model using Firebase ML Kit.

I have already uploaded the model to Firebase (as a tf lite model).

My model takes a (56, 75, 3) pixel image as input and attempts to classify the image into 4 classes.

I am struggling to resize the bitmap properly to fit inside a byte array which is {1, 56, 75, 3}

```
bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage); //getting bitmap from camera

//Boilerplate code to set up Firebase

FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions = new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder().setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.BYTE, new int[]{1, 56, 75, 3}).setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.BYTE, new int[]{1, 4}).build();

Bitmap scaled_bitmap Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 56, 75, true)
```

How do I convert the Bitmap to a [1][56][75][3] byte array so I can feed in the bitmap to the model?

```
byte[][][][] input = new byte[1][56][75][3];
input = ?? need help here to convert bitmap to byte array
```